# Monaco editor worker

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix, monaco-editor

So I am currently trying to setup Monaco editor with this package: https://github.com/egoist/vue-monaco

It works beautifully, except for one error message:

```
Could not create web worker(s). Falling back to loading web worker code in main thread, which might cause UI freezes. Please see https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor#faq

You must define a function MonacoEnvironment.getWorkerUrl or MonacoEnvironment.getWorker
```

Now I understand you need to spin up a worker, however, I can't seem to get this working properly.

I've been using Laravel & Laravel Mix to get this all working, however there seems no documentation on how to setup the worker.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This message means that Monaco could not create its webworkers (there can be one for TS and one for JS). Check the invironment you are running your code in, if that allows to create/use webworkers.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this same error message. You have to configure the monaco editor webpack plugin.

Install it via `npm i monaco-editor-webpack-plugin`, then add the plugin to your webpack config:

```js
const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin');

export default {
    // ...

    plugins: [new MonacoWebpackPlugin()],
}
```